# How do I make my own version of a "resx" file in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: xml, xslt, visual-studio-2013, c#

How do you create an xml file that can automatically create a *.designer.cs file similar to how *.resx files do so?

Basically, I have an xml file (`foo.xyz`). When it is updated, I want it to automatically create (or update) a *.designer.cs file that is `DependantUpon` the main `foo.xyz` file. I have no idea what this process is even called to know how to search for any relevant information about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Resx code behind is generated using PublicResXFileCodeGenerator VS custom tool. Here is a example on how to create new VS Custom tool, its for VS 2008 but I think the same process is in 2013:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31257/Custom-Tools-Explained

Maybe for your needs it will be easier to go with [T4 template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) code generation.